# How do I upload images with Flask and requests?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to make an API that when a POST request is made, it will accept images and then save them, and if a GET request is made then it will send back a URL to where you'd be able to download that image. How would that be possible?

This is the Flask app running on localhost for testing:

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/upload_image/<filename>", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image(filename):
    # receive the image here
    # ...

@app.route("/get_image", methods=["GET"])
def get_image():
    filename = "encoded_image.png"
    return send_file(filename, mimetype="image/png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=5000)
```

I think sending the image is easy but I don't know how to go about receiving it and using `requests` to send it.

This is the idea behind the main code:

```py
import requests

option = input()

if option == "get image":
    print("Download the image at: https://localhost:5000/get_image")
elif option == "upload image":
    post = requests.post("https://localhost:5000/upload_image/encoded_image.png")
```

i don't want the images to change names. I always want to send the file `encoded_image.png` and receive it, because I want it to be overwritten when the `POST` is made. This is for a discord bot but that doesn't really affect anything, I just thought I'd mention it. Thanks in advance :)